# 1/2" to 3/4" gap between tub and tile

Tags: tile, bathtub, grout

The question has been asked on this forum before about what to do when tilers have started the tile too high from the tub. But my gap is even larger, and I have tried the caulk solution to ugly effect, needing layers and layers, which never look good (and tried different kinds including one that got really yellow). A backer rod to minimize the gap never seems to work either as it's not deep.

Recently I got the tub refinished (yep, $675 every ten years until I want to demo the whole bathroom) and the guy suggested white cement for the problem.

I went to Lowe's today and also found Mapei brand of sanded grout that says it goes up to 3/4" gaps. The Lowe's guy was somewhat dubious as he thought it would crack, but maybe sealing and caulking over it in same color would make it work.

Whatever I do, I will need to tape off, blanket the tub, and do it gently, and preferably ONCE, because with these refinished tubs you don't want to be chipping away at something that didn't work out.

So, how can I fill that 3/4" gap?

[image]

Comment: What does it look like when zoomed out?  Could you remove the bottom row of tiles and find an accent tile that is slightly taller?  The transition between the tile and the tub has to be caulked - when the tub fills with water it will drop and caulking will stretch - grout won't.

Comment: I am leery of removing tile and opening a can of worms. Planning to sell in six months so just want to make it passable. New people will undoubtedly remodel someday. Is there any grout that is more "stretchy" though, to allow for some expansion when the tub is full of water?

Comment: Anyone have a take on the white cement suggestion?

Comment: You could probably use a piece of plastic laminate that is normally used as a backsplash.  Cut it to the height and use thinset to adhere it to the gap then caulk it to the tub/tile (your bottom row of tile doesn't look particularly level so you could maybe get a cleaner look.)  I can't imagine trying to parge that gap with white concrete.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Could probably cut laminate that thin, whereas tile would be impossible.

Comment: laminate shears work well - MA72500-Klenk-Straight-Laminate-Shear